# How do i solve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException'

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have just created new `ASP.NET Core Web Application`  using predefined templates e.g `File > New > Project > Asp.Net Core Web Application'.

I select `.NET Core 2.0` with Angular template.
I am using VS 2017.
The node version installed on my machine is `4.2.2`
NPM version is `2.14.7`

When i run i get exception

> {Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException:
>   Unexpected token { SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>       at require (module.js:385:17)
>       at Object. (c:\users\MyApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:30:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.d__7`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.d__13`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.d__10`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason i see for this problem is basically you are using older versions of Node and NPM. Like you said `"The node version installed on my machine is 4.2.2 NPM version is 2.14.7"`

You need to update them 
`Node: 6.11.2`
`NPM: 3.10.10.`

Then problem shall be fixed.

Comment: OK lemme check!!

Comment: Yes thanks it worked after i have upgraded both my Node and Npm versions.